# angular $resource with jsonp not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm having troubles w/ the following code:

```
angular.module('offerServices', ['ngResource'])
    .factory('Offer', function ($resource) {

        return $resource('url/offers', { callback: 'JSON_CALLBACK' },
            {
                query: { method: 'JSONP' }
            }
        );                   

    })
    .factory('Trustyou', function ($resource) {
            return $resource('https://api.trustyou.com/hotels/:id/seal.json', {},
                {
                    query: { method: 'JSONP' }
                }
            );
    });
```

calling Offer.query({}, function(){}); in my controller works without any problems.
but this part is not working:

```
       var trustYouData = Trustyou.query({ id: 'd8421e79-99f0-41b2-8d6e-9cfd62a9776b' }, function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        });
```

this always returns a 400 error:

"NetworkError: 400 Bad Request - https://api.trustyou.com/hotels/d8421e79-99f0-41b2-8d6e-9cfd62a9776b/seal.json?callback=angular.callbacks._1"

when I change my code and use jQuerys.getJSON, I don't have any issues:

```
 $.getJSON("https://api.trustyou.com/hotels/d8421e79-99f0-41b2-8d6e-9cfd62a9776b/seal.json?callback=?", function (data) {
            console.log(data);                           
        });
```

Why is the jQuery method working but angulars $resource implementation returns an error in this case?

Comment: Have you tried `GET` instead of `JSONP`? Also, at the time you posted the question, was the format the same as the current response of the URL?

Comment: yeah I've tried $http.get as well, and the format was the same ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's some issue with the callback function on angular, i've open an issue in git

https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/1551

The callback name must be "JSONP_CALLBACK" in which angular will turn the callback name to callback=angular.callbacks._1

There's some web web service which cannot accept "angular.callbacks._1 "callback name.

solution :

```
var stock_hack

function stock_search(data) {
    stock_hack = data;
 }


var stock_hack

function stock_search(data) {
    stock_hack = data;
}


function jsonp_example($scope, $http) {

    $scope.doRequest = function() {
        $http({
            method: "JSONP",
            params: {
                input: "GM",
                callback: "stock_search"
            },
            url: "http://dev.markitondemand.com/Api/Lookup/jsonp",
            isArray: true
        }).success(function(data, status) {
/*
                 *Never Goes HERE !!
                 */


        }).error(function(data, status) {

/*
                 * FREAKING HACK !!!!
                 */
            console.info("goes here")
            console.info(stock_hack)

        });
    };


}​
```

My fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/pMGgR/

The point is you must call another javascript function to get your json respone.

Hope this help

Comment: Thank you @Todi! You're right, apparently the web service I'm using is not compatible w/ angular's callback handler 'callback=angular.callbacks._1'. Your solution works great for now! Hope this issue is being fixed soon! +1

Comment: I don't understand why the code in this answer has the stock_hack var and the stock_search() function defined twice.  Is that a typo?

Comment: @TodiAdiatmo, as JeffryHouser said, 
I don't understand why the code in this answer has the stock_hack var and the stock_search() function defined twice. Is that a typo?

Answer (score 0):

I thought I would add a real solution to this problem. This is a working solution.

Here is the code

```
var symbol = 'NFLX';
var url = "http://dev.markitondemand.com/Api/v2/Lookup/jsonp?input="+ symbol +"&callback=JSON_CALLBACK";

$http.jsonp(url)
.success(function(data){
   console.info(data);
}).error(function(data, status) {
   console.info(data);
});
```

Returns

```
//[{"Symbol":"NFLX","Name":"Netflix Inc","Exchange":"NASDAQ"}]
```

[Click here to go to the direct link](http://dev.markitondemand.com/Api/v2/Lookup/jsonp?input=NFLX&callback=JSON_CALLBACK)