# JSON_CALLBACK not found using JSONP

Tags: angularjs, jsonp

I am trying to get a JSONP response working using the following code...

```
$http.jsonp('http://example.com:8888/?callback=JSON_CALLBACK').success( function( response )
{
    console.dir( response );
});
```

http://example.com:8888/?callback=JSON_CALLBACK returns the following via node.js

> JSON_CALLBACK({ date:'2013-05-15T08:53:51.747Z' });

The header is being set in node.js like this....

```
res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
```

Yet the error I get in a Chrome console is this...

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: JSON_CALLBACK is not defined
```

However, weirdly, If I create the function `window.JSON_CALLBACK(response)` it will run. But I thought that success is meant to do that on my behalf.

Answer (score 2):

Your content-type header is not correct.

Use `application/json` if what you return is plain JSON. JSONP is Javascript, so you should use `application/javascript`

Comment: Thank you for your response, but I did try that. I had the same error

Comment: Me too @tomwrong. I noticed it has to do with the naming of the file. I tried changing the name of my api (a php file) and or changing the JSON_CALLBACK to angular.callbacks._0 in the php file. I think this is a bug of angular.

Comment: i think its not a bug, i think its to offer more than one callback

Answer (score 0):

See [angular $resource with jsonp not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13267285/angular-resource-with-jsonp-not-working)
This issue have been opened in git: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/1551

Answer (score 0):

I found this hack and it's work for me

```
    //.........................ini: Hack
    /*
        Copy-Paste this code just before your $http request.
    */      
        var c = $window.angular.callbacks.counter.toString(36);

        $window['angularcallbacks_' + c] = function (data) {
            $window.angular.callbacks['_' + c](data);
            delete $window['angularcallbacks_' + c];
        };     
    //.........................end: Hack

    //Your $http request
    $http.jsonp(url)
     .success(function(){
        console.log("ok")
    })
     .error(function(data, status, headers, config){
        console.error("ko");
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick and dirty solution. Instead of outputting `JSON_CALLBACK({ date:'2013-05-15T08:53:51.747Z' })`, you can try to output `angular.callbacks._0({ date:'2013-05-15T08:53:51.747Z' })`. I believe this is bug in Angular.

An alternative is to request your url this way:

```
$http({
  method: 'JSONP',
  url: 'https://something.com/' + '?callback=JSON_CALLBACK' + '&otherstuffs'
});
```

PS. If you use php backend, I noticed changing the name of the php file will sometimes have positive result (like instead of using index.php we can try api.php). Although it seems to be completely random (what name works and vise versa) - I think this has to do with how Angular read the url of the json.

It looks like the reason of this unfortunate bug is that Angular will replace the `JSON_CALLBACK` to `angular.callbacks._0` but it will fail sometimes due to its URL interpreter.

Additionally, even if it succeeded the server you are using may not support the `?callback=angular.callbacks._0` in the url (which is a common behavior among servers).