# JSONP Request is not getting the result in Angular JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am requesting three urls in AngularJs by Using JSONP.

For the first time i am getting the values. But after second call i am not getting any value.
When i see the console i found this error.

> Exception: TypeError: 'caller', 'callee', and 'arguments' properties
>   may not be accessed on strict mode functions or the arguments objects
>   for calls to them

What is this error meant by?

Here is my sample code.

```
appPortal.controller('HistoCtrl', ['$rootScope', '$scope', '$http', '$location',
    function($rootScope, $scope, $http, $location) {
        console.log($rootScope);

        $scope.url1 = '';
        $scope.url2 = '';
        $scope.url3 = '';

        //request handler
        $scope.sendDataRequest = function() {
            $http.jsonp($scope.url1).then(function(msg) {
                console.log(msg.data);
            });
            $http.jsonp($scope.url2).then(function(msg) {
                console.log(msg.data);
            });
            $http.jsonp($scope.url3).then(function(msg) {
                console.log(msg.data);
            });
        };

        //get current month data
        $scope.getCurrentMonthData = function() {
            $scope.url1 = $rootScope.ApiWeatherHost + '/climo/v1/actuals/' + $scope.location_key + '?callback=JSON_CALLBACK&start=' + $scope.start + '&end=' + $scope.end + '&apikey=' + $rootScope.ApiKey;
            $scope.url2 = $rootScope.ApiWeatherHost + '/climo/v1/records/' + $scope.location_key + '?callback=JSON_CALLBACK&start=' + $scope.start + '&end=' + $scope.end + '&apikey=' + $rootScope.ApiKey;
            $scope.url3 = $rootScope.ApiWeatherHost + '/climo/v1/normals/' + $scope.location_key + '?callback=JSON_CALLBACK&start=' + $scope.start + '&end=' + $scope.end + '&apikey=' + $rootScope.ApiKey;
            $scope.sendDataRequest();
        };
    }
]);
```

I am try to get these rest API Using the Jsonp

http://api.accuweather.com/developers/climoAPIguide

Comment: Maybe show more code, you said you issue three requests.

Comment: @dfsq 
PLease refer this.. i am having similar issue..
https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/1551

Comment: @dfsq I saw the request out put for my url. The out put is not attaching the Angular.callback_0.1. 
is this necessary in the output for jsonp request ?

Comment: Try the solution referenced here:

  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13267285/angular-resource-with-jsonp-not-working

Comment: @ChadRobinson http://codepen.io/dustin/pen/DJIKi